# Access the 'parent' data.frame after using group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to compare the standard deviation for a variable, to the standard deviations of the variable once grouped by a factor.

This is the overall sd()

```
require(dplyr)

iris %.% summarise(
  Overall.SD = sd(Sepal.Length)
  )
```

However, I can't access it once I have used group_by

```
iris %.%
  group_by(Species) %.%
  summarise(
    Species.SD = sd(Sepal.Length),
    Overall.SD = sd(iris$Sepal.Length),
    Species.SD < Overall.SD
  )
```

Is there a way to make dplyr look back to the overall dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would compute the `Overall.SD` before grouping the data using `mutate` so that the other data is kept as it was.

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(Overall.SD = sd(Sepal.Length)) %>%   # you can use mutate instead of summarise here
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(Species.SD = sd(Sepal.Length), 
              Overall.SD = Overall.SD[1],    # You could also remove this line if you just want the comparison and don't need to display the actual Overall.SD
              Species.SD < Overall.SD)
```

Comment: That's a nice way to do it.  I hadn't thought to take the first case with `Overall.SD[1]` and assign it in that way. Thank you